# Calling a function in one external file from a function in another external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep reading that it is possible to load javascript files, and then use those functions in other files.  Unfortunately I can't get this to work.  Here is my current path:

```
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/twitter_crypt.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        <script src="js/interactive.js"></script>
```

I am using functions from the `twitter_crypt.js` file in my `interactive.js` file (last in path).

When I console.log(nameOfFunction) in `interactive.js` which is in `twitter_crypt.js`it tells me that function is not defined.

I ran into this [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951645/reference-multiple-js-files-in-a-single-line-in-a-html-file) but I am not looking to use something like require.js .

I am just trying to call functions from the other files. I assume the must be available since I am using jquery, bootstra.min.js and other files that are being loaded.

I believe I have everything in order as well which is what this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481113/calling-a-function-from-one-javascript-file-which-requires-another) talks about.

//Twitter_Crypt JS file:

```
function decoder(key, encodedMessage){
    var coded = "";
    var ch;
    var index;
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for(var i = 0; i < encodedMessage.length; i++){
        ch = encodedMessage.charAt(i);
        index = key.indexOf(ch);
        if(index === -1){
            coded = coded + ch;
        } else {
            coded = coded + alphabet.charAt(index);
        }
    }
    return coded;

}
```

InteractivJS File:

```
$('#decodeSubmit').on("click", function(ev){
        if($("#encryptText").val() === ""){
            alert("Please Enter a Decrypted Tweet");
        } else {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var decodedTweet = decoder("zipsunxmogdkfabrhcylvqewtj", $("#encryptText").val());
        $("#decode_form").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#decode").fadeIn("fast");
            $('#decode_progress').progressbar({
                display_text: 'center', 
                use_percentage: false, 
                refresh_speed: 10,
                done: function($this) { 
                    $(".modal-body").append(decodedTweet).css('color', 'black');
                    $("#decodeNewTweet").fadeIn("slow");
                    $(".modal").modal("show");
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

When I put the function decoder inside the interactiveJS file it works fine. When it is in the twitter_crypt.js file I keep getting a decoder is not defined.

Originally I had both scripts wrapped in a document ready, which helped but didn't solve everything. Why isn't my decoder function in global scope though? It isn't wrapped in any other functions?

Do I have to do something like `window.decoder =function(){}`

Comment: Then either the function isn't defined, or it isn't in the global scope. We can't see the code in your scripts to tell.

Comment: Yeah, whatever functions you're using need to be exported into the global scope from that script.

Comment: I did find one problem -- `I assume`. Don't assume. Find out. Copy the script from the file into your page as if it were a standard script instead of a linked script. See if it alters the result.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the suggestions, I added some of the code in both of my files, these scripts don't work together, I believe they are both in global scope as well and loading in the proper order.

Comment: Perhaps try running stuff in the Firebug console, e.g. `decoder("zipsunxmogdkfabrhcylvqewtj", "hello"`

Comment: What happens when you try window.decoder = decoder in the file where decoder is implemented? Try window.decoder in the console after having done that.